# Why no variable size array in stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-data

I don't really understand why I can't have a variable size array on the stack, so something like

```
foo(int n) {
   int a[n];
}
```

As I understand the stack(-segment) of part of the data-segment and thus it is not of "constant size".

Comment: I don't think there is any technical reason, since C99 added that capability.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Mostly, it's tricky to do, and we already have `std::vector`, so they didn't require compilers to do it.  On the other hand, gcc and msvc can both do it anyway.

Comment: Could be because historically applications had less memory dedicated to stacks.  Also stacks were a fixed structure containing local variables, parameter values and return addresses.  For platforms with fixed size stacks, this feature could be dangerous.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That explanation doesn't hold up in any language that supports recursion.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, being dangerous has never stopped a feature from being added to C++. You're expected to know what you're doing.

Comment: @MooingDuck, any compiler that supports both C++ and C99 would be expected to allow it in C++ as an extension. As for being tricky, I can imagine quite easily how it would be implemented, and I don't write compilers.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I didn't think so either until I realized that what if you have local variables in a more inner scope than the VLA, or two VLAs?  Then the offset of each variable is no longer a constant more than the frame pointer.  I can see how that might lead to complexity.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Variable Length Arrays(VLA)** are not allowed in C++ as per the C++ standard.
Many compilers including gcc support them as a compiler extension, but it is important to note that any code that uses such an extension is non portable.

C++ provides **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)** for implementing a similar functionality as **VLA**.

---

There was a **[proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2648.html)** to introduce Variable Length Arrays in C++11, but eventually was dropped, because it would need large changes to the type system in C++. The benefit of being able to create small arrays on stack without wasting space or calling constructors for not used elements was considered not significant enough for large changes in C++ type system.

Comment: That, and alloca can be used with placement new[]. Though it will get rather messy in the multidimensional cases.

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to explain this with an example:

Say you have this function:

```
int myFunc() {
   int n = 16;
   int arr[n];
   int k = 1;
}
```

When the program runs, it sets the variables in this way onto the stack:

```
- n @relative addr 0
- arr[16] @relative addr 4
- k @relative addr 64
TOTAL SIZE: 68 bytes
```

Let's say I want to resize arr to 4 elements. I'm going to do:

```
delete arr;
arr = new int[4];
```

Now: if i leave the stack this way, the stack will have holes of unused space. So the most intelligent thing to do is to move all the variables from one place to another in the stack and recompute their positions. But we are missing something: C++ does not set the positions on the fly, it is done only once, when you compile the program. Why? It is straightforward: because there is no real need of having variable size objects onto the stack, and because having them would slow down all the programs when allocating/reallocating stack space.

This is not the only problem, there is another, even bigger one:
When you allocate an array, you decide how much space it will take and the compiler can warn you if you exceed the available space, instead if you let the program allocate variable size arrays on your stack, you are opening breaches in security, since you make all the programs that use this kind of method vulnerable to stack-overflows.

Comment: What do you mean you're going to do `delete arr;`? Who ever said that would be valid? `arr` isn't a pointer.

Comment: arr is NOT a pointer, but that would be the only (currently known) way of unallocating it. It's just a theoretical way to explain how it would work.

Comment: We're talking about C99 VLAs, they're well-defined; no hypotheticals needed. `arr` is automatically allocated.

Comment: Absolutely not. We are talking about why those are not implemented as a standard. And C99 VLAs are not even mentioned in the question, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

**Note that the proposal was rejected and the following is no longer true.  It may be revived for a future version of C++ though.**

VLA as described in N3639 has been accepted in Bristol meeting and will become part of C++14, as well as a library counter-part "dynarray". So using compiler with C++14 support we can start writing something like:

```
void func(int n)
{
    int arr[n];
}
```

Or use dynarray:

```
#include <dynarray>

void func(int n)
{
    std::dynarray<int> arr(n);
}
```

Comment: Note: it was later un-accepted and did not make it into C++14.

Comment: Please delete this answer, it is (eventually) incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: because it is not defined in the C++ standard.

Not so simple answer: Because no one propsed something behaving coherently for C++ in that case. From the standards POV there is no stack, it could be implemented totally differently. C99 has VLAs, but they seem to be so complex to implement that gcc only finished the implementation in 4.6. I don't think many people will want to propose something for C++ and see compiler manufacturers struggle with it for many years.

Comment: Both GCC and MSVC implement it, but you're right that I heard complaints from both.

Comment: @MooingDuck: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/c99status.html seems to indicate that this wasn't easy already for C99. And with stuff like dtors and exceptions and whatnot I believe it is quite hard for C++. If it would be made standard, many more would have to implement it. I don't think many people want a second `export`. IMHO There are many more important things to change for future, than VLAs, which are a nice feature, but not indispensible.

Answer (score 1):

Stacks are fairly small, and their sizes can vary dramatically per architecture. The problem is that it is fairly easy to 'over-allocate' and cause a seg fault or write over memory owned by somebody else. Meanwhile, solutions to the problem (e.g. `vector`) have existed for a long time.

FWIW, I read Stroustrup say that he didn't *want* them, but I don't know which interview it was in.

Answer (score 0):

Because in C++ a static array needs a static constant size, so it is not allowed by the language. Note that C99 does support vararrays at the stack, and some implementations support it under C++ as well as an extension.

Comment: Right, the question is *why* this is so in C++. Why didn't they follow C99's idea and add them?

Comment: I think you're on the right track here.  I can't prove this, but I believe that, for various reasons, *all* objects in C++ need a constant size.  Why though?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Constant or Non Zero size? Are you confusing the two?

Comment: @Als: Constant.  One of the reasons I think this is because I have no idea what would be expected if a VLA was passed to the following function: `template<int N> void foo(int (&arr)[N])`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Ah,okay, that would be interesting to know if We can find more context about it in the Standard then.

Answer (score -1):

Because the language specification says so. Nothing else matters (and explaining with segments is terribly wrong for different reasons).

Comment: @user695652 For starters, because there are no segments in C++.

Comment: I find this answer intellectually lazy. It's not like the standard simply came into existence from nothing, people worked on it. Why didn't those people follow the route of C99's VLAs?

Comment: @GMan: Well, following the route of C99 VLAs in C++98 seems to be not easy for the reason of 98 < 99 ;) I think for the intrested it would be intresting to read all the mailings and proposals in the C++98 standardization process; I am not sure, but I think people proposed something, as a term to search for try "dynarray". But don't take my word for it, weak memory, you know...

Comment: @GMan It isn't lazyism. It's dogmatism. It's different!

Comment: @PlasmaHH: There is an 03 standard as well as the new 11 standard, is what I meant.