# variable length array-like parts in class and class template in C++

Tags: c++

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282804/is-declaring-a-local-array-based-on-function-arguments-legal-in-c) before. But now I am wondering why the following is also valid or invalid:

```
class C {
    int n;
    int a[n];
};
template <typename T, int n> class A {
    int a[n];
};
```

I tested them in g++ and they seemed to work. Are they the same as VLA in the case when inside a function, or they are different? Besides, I can now make the array parts on heap besides on stack too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st isn't valid unless `n` is constant. If it was allowed, `sizeof` wouldn't work correctly.

2nd. isn't truly a VLA, as `n` has to be constant:

```
void foo(int n) {
  A<int, n> x; // error
}
```

If you want semi-portable VLAs then use `alloca` function. Or use std::vector if you don't care about it being on the heap.

```
void foo(int n) {
  int a[n];                         // VLA extension, somewhat portable
  int* b = alloca(n * sizeof(int)); // alloca, somewhat portable (should work on MSVC)
  std::vector<int> c(n);            // portable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A VLA has its size determined at runtime. VLAs are not in C++, even though `g++` implements them.

Since templates are a compile-time mechanism, the array `A::a` will have its size determined at compile time. The array `C::a` is invalid, though, because `c::n` is not a compile time constant.

Try compiling with warnings enabled and with `-std=c++98` or `-std=c++0x`.