# Trying to get rid of any heap memory allocation

Tags: c++, stack, heap-memory

I know how to do it with heap memory, but I try to get rid of any heap memory allocation in my code.

I cannot use any library which can help me, it means: `<string>` for example.

How can I do it with using stack memory allocation?

```
int main(void) {
    class Animal {
        unsigned char nameLength;
        unsigned char name[];

        setName(unsigned char name[]) {
            memcpy(this->name, name, this->length * sizeof(unsigned char));
        }
    }

    Animal dog;

    // The value '4' isn't constant, it depends on received data from socket
    dog.nameLength = 4;

    // Right now I know how many elements will be in dog.name array

    unsigned char randomName[dog.nameLength];

    // Here will be a for loop, but just for example:
    randomName[0] = "B";
    randomName[1] = "e";
    randomName[2] = "n";
    randomName[3] = "/0";

    dog.setName(randomName);

    // Expected output: dog.name = "Ben\0"
}
```

The for loop will look like:

```
unsigned char i;
for (i = 0; i < (dog.nameLength-1); i++) {
    randomName[i] = packet[i];
}
randomName[i] = 0;
```

Comment: The [mcve] you show have multiple problems, all unrelated to the problem you ask about.

Comment: And the only way to solve the problem you ask about is to define `Animal::name` with a fixed length, large enough to hold all possible strings you might need.

Comment: Lastly, *why* can't you use any heap allocation? Is it an assignment requirement? What *is* your assignment? What are its requirements? And please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `unsigned char randomName[dog.nameLength];` this is not valid C++ because of VLA

Comment: What is `this->length` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues.

But for the main issue: in general it is a very bad idea to do what you are trying to do (allocate dynamically on the stack), this is exactly what heap allocations are for.

Also, standard C++ does not allow this. There are, however, compiler extensions you could use: [Why no variable size array in stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812566/why-no-variable-size-array-in-stack) and linux has alloca: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html & [C++ How to allocate memory dynamically on stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335023/c-how-to-allocate-memory-dynamically-on-stack)