# Why is this program not producing any output (std::cout, fibonacci series)?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    arr[0]=1;
    arr[1]=1;
    if(1<=n&&n<=1000)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[i-1]+arr[i-2];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i];
    }
    cout<<arr[n-1];
    return 0;
}
```

The program asks user to enter 'n' and then the program ends without any output.

Output:

```
6


...Program finished with exit code 0 Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: Variable length arrays (`int arr[n]`) are not standard C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812566/why-no-variable-size-array-in-stack

Comment: Be aware of that `int arr[n];` when `n` isn't `constexpr` is not supported by standard C++. Use `std::vector<int> arr(n);` instead.

Comment: Terminology: ***Compiler** asks user to enter 'n'* -> ***Program** asks user to enter 'n'*. The compiler has long since finished its job by the time you run the program.

Comment: Fibonacci 1000 = 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
I'm curious where you're going to store that.

Comment: Your program only accepts inputs less than 1 or greater than 1000. Did you mean `if (n < 1 || n > 1000) { return 0; }`?

Answer (score 3):

It exits here:

```
    if(1<=n&&n<=1000)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

because `6` is greater than `0` and less than `1000`

Comment: Or in OP:s notation: `1 <= 6 && 6 <= 1000` (1 is less than or equal to 6) and (6 is less than or equal to 1000).